# bar scanner for MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, barcode-scanner

I've been looking into making an iOS app which uses the camera to take a photograph of a barcode (such as code 39) and reading them in properly.

Was just looking at a few libraries, not sure if any work as I'd like but they're all using objective-c for iOS.

Thought maybe I should ask if there is a solution in MonoTouch since that is how I want to make the app for iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar [thread](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2011-September/005337.html) running on MonoTouch mailing-list.

[RedLaser](http://redlaser.com/mobile/) [latest](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2011-September/005349.html) (newer than mono's git repository) bindings are available at: https://github.com/chrisbranson/monotouch-bindings
with sample code available at: https://github.com/chrisbranson/RedLaserSample

Another suggestion was using: https://github.com/GoranHalvarsson/BarcodeReader-MonoTouch

Other people have using the (commercial) [LineaPro](http://www.ipcprint.com/) SDK (some MonoTouch bindings are available on github too).

Answer (score 2):

Here is another one by Redth:

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

His example usage:

```
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
scanner.Scan().ContinueWith((result) => {   
   if (result != null)
     Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Monotouch to bind the native objective-c libary to your monotouch project.

You can find detail information about this topic here:

<strike>http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types</strike> (**NOT AVAILABLE ANYMORE**)

You can find a ready to use binding for RedLaser on Github:
https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings

Answer (score 0):

Mine also works:

<strike>http://www.jmawebtechstore.com/p/21/ios-monotouch-barcode-scanner-reader</strike> (**WEB CONTENT NOT AVAILABLE ANYMORE**)

I have a whole barcode scanning app available with source code. My app saves barcodes to the database and photos to the photo album.